# C# Convert hex string to decimal . Why negative value?

Tags: c#

The HEX -> DEC code below for some values return negative value.

f.x  HEX: a4ddfc12  should be: 2766011410 but the C# for some reason return: -1528955886

Code:  https://rextester.com/SHSC23645

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myHexStr = "a4ddfc12";
            Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(myHexStr, 
System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It will be the same if I use this:
    Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(Convert.ToInt32(myHexStr, 16).ToString();

Expected to get:  2766011410

Comment: it will convert properly if we use this:   https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Comment: Have you tried starting off your hex string with "0x"?

Comment: The value you got is the "Decimal from signed 2's complement".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is too big to fit in a 32-bit integer, which maxes out at 2147483647, and [overflows](https://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/understanding-arithmetic-overflow-checking-in-c-sharp/).

Use a 64-bit integer instead:

```
string myHexStr = "a4ddfc12";

Console.WriteLine(Int64.Parse(myHexStr, NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString());  // 2766011410
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that (as it was in my case) it's being interpreted as a negative number due to the binary matching "[Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)", leading to it becoming the negative complement version. To fix this I only had to add a leading "0" to the string I was parsing.

To avoid overflows I used BigInteger.

```
// Outputs negative number
BigInteger.Parse("af63f108eeca2000", NumberStyles.HexNumber);

// Outputs positive (unsigned) number
BigInteger.Parse("0" + "af63f108eeca2000", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

If you are working with the hex format with the leading `0x`, then add the 0 after the `0x`. So `"0xaf63f108eeca2000"` should be `"0x0af63f108eeca2000"`.